# Create video from image sequence starting at image_100

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to convert a sequence of images into a .mov file. The command line I use is:

```
ffmpeg.exe -f image2 -i im_%04d.jpeg -r 25 -sameq -vcodec mjpeg out.mov
```

It works fine if the first image of the sequence starts at im_0000, but when the first image starts for example at im_0100, then I get an

```
im_%04d.jpeg: Error number -2 occurred
```

How can I force it to analyse the sequence, no matter what number the first image is?

Answer (score 9):

It is old question, but i think that answer should be here:

You may use "-start_number 100"

[FFmpeg documentation](http://www.ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-do-I-encode-single-pictures-into-movies_003f)